# How to hide recycle bin link in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, navigation, quick-launch, recycle-bin

[image: Example]

I want to remove the link "Recycle bin" of that menu, but when I try to edit it, I can't see it in the editors option.

Somebody know how to remove it from the menu?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the recycle bin menu from navigation/quick launch by activating **SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure** feature on your site.

Once you activate this feature at site collection and site level, you can edit the navigation menu & remove recycle bin link.

**Reference**: [SharePoint Online: Hide Recycle Bin from Quick Launch](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2020/04/sharepoint-online-hide-recycle-bin-from-quick-launch.html) - Check case 2

Comment: Neither option on that site is supported.